# usnparser json-like data to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I have usnparser data that outputs like below (arbitratry fields):

```
{
 "thisisafield":"THISISAVALUE",
 "thisisanewf": "ThisIsANewVal",
 "LastField":"LastValue"
}
{
 "thisisafield":"THISISAVALUE1",
 "thisisanewf": "ThisIsANewVal1",
 "LastField":"LastValue1"
}
```

I am trying to read it with pandas like below:

```
data = pathtomyfile
pd.read_json(data, orient='records')
```

I have also tried to use json like below:

data = json.dumps(pathtomyfile)
   pd.read_json(data,orient='records')

How can i get my data to a pandas dataframe?

Comment: this looks like dict to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to go, but you'll need to edit the data within the file:

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

with open(pathtomyfile) as f:
    data = f.read()
    data = '[' + data.replace('\n', '').replace('}', '},') + ']' #convert it to list of dicts
    df = pd.DataFrame(ast.literal_eval(data))
    df
#thisisafield  thisisanewf    LastField
#THISISAVALUE  ThisIsANewVal  LastValue
#THISISAVALUE1 ThisIsANewVal1 LastValue1
```

And to turn your data `json` dumpable make it like this:

```
data = '[' + data.replace('\n', '').replace('}', '},', data.count('}')-1) + ']'
df = pd.read_json(data)
```